# how can i open a modal from other component in react js functional component react-modal

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-modal

newbie in react here may I request for your assistance on below?

wont able to open modal component from other function component

can i get an e.g in which one component have modal and from other component we can open that modal in react js with react-modal package
thank you.

Need help

Answer (score 0):

In App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Model from "./Model";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { status: false, text: "" };
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ status: !prev.status }));
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const { status, text } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Open photo entry dialog</button>
        <ChildComponent
          isOpen={status}
          text={text}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
const ChildComponent = ({ isOpen, text, handleChange, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {isOpen && (
        <Model
          status={isOpen}
          handleClick={handleClick}
          text={text}
          handleChange={handleChange}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

In Model.js

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Button, Modal, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Model({ handleClick, status, handleChange, text }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={status} onHide={handleClick}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Gallary</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={text}
            placeholder="Enter Something"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Modal.Body>
          Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal from your input:{" "}
          <strong>{text}</strong>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClick}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClick}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires passing a function as props. I am assuming there is some relation between both the components so you must be calling the second component from the first component.

## **Solution**

Let's call the component that contains Modal as C1 and the component that needs to open the Modal as C2
You need to pass a function as props from C1 to C2 which opens the Modal. 
Define the function openModal in C1:

```
openModal(){                               \\Function to open the Modal
  this.setState({modal:true})              \\modal state is used to define the state of the modal. When it is true, the modal is open.
}
```

Pass openModal function from C1 to C2 by using this in C1:

```
<C2 openModal={this.openModal} />
```

Now, in C2 use this script to open the Modal:

```
this.props.openModal()                      \\Use this in the event which opens the Modal
```

Answer (score 0):

use redux or any state management library to track open state